# How to create and copy content of column in a .txt file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to create a text file and copy the content of, lets say, column J to column L inside the newly created text file? I know you can write some text inside the text file by writing the text directly inside the code but is there a methode or a fonction that copy content of a column?

Comment: Do you want to separate the columns with commas (CSV files), or with tabs (like copy to clipboard) or with fixed width and trim the contents?

Comment: well the simplest would be good but i would like it to be like a copy to clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code to manually create a CSV text file. You can modify this to suit your needs

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExportToCSV(ByVal rngStart As Range, ByVal fname As String, Optional n_rows As Long = 0, Optional n_columns As Long = 0)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    If n_rows = 0 Then
        n_rows = rngStart.Worksheet.Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
    If n_columns = 0 Then
        n_columns = rngStart.Worksheet.Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
    End If

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fs As TextStream
    Set fs = fso.CreateTextFile(fname)

    Dim line As String, vals() As Variant
    vals = rngStart.Resize(n_rows, n_columns).Value
    For i = 1 To n_rows
        line = CStr(vals(i, 1))
        For j = 2 To n_columns
            line = line & "," & CStr(vals(i, j))
        Next j
        fs.WriteLine line
    Next i
    fs.Close
End Sub
```

Make sure you have `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` added as a reference which gives you access to `FileSystemObject`.

[image: FSO]

You call the code with

```
ExportToCSV Range("G1"), "Export.txt", 0, 3
```

if either the number of rows or columns is zero, then the code will find the end of the data for the export. In the example above, all used rows, but three columns are going to be exported in to the file.

[image: result]

PS. To change to tab-delimited code, like what you would get from copying into the windows clipboard, change the `","` with `vbTab`. That's it.

Comment: woaw tnx! and i was curius! is there a reason why people are rough on here? like i got 3 dislike in about 30 min and i don't understand what's wrong?

Comment: @alexilas - I don't know. Some people may consider this a _trivial_ piece of code and wouldn't be bothered answering so they are annoyed that a question was asked that has answers elsewhere. I think the devil is in the details always, and even seemingly trivial questions have merit.

Comment: well thanks to both of you to take the time to answer my question!! very kind.